# What linguistic category would informal contractions fall under?

Tags: syntax, morphology, vocabulary

I'm sure this question has an extremely simple answer, but I'm comparing the dialects from two movies, one being a typical Hollywood movie, and one being a documentary. I am listing any linguistic difference from Standard English into their categories so that I can compare the two.

Currently I'm focusing on differences in Phonetics, Syntax and Vocabulary. However, I noticed that one of the dialects uses informal contractions (whaddya, whatcha, ain't, oughta, outta) very frequently and was wondering what category they would fit into.

Comment: Whatever category their unabbreviated counterparts have.

Answer (score 3):

The linguistics concept that best matches what you are interested in is "register", within the field of sociolinguistics.

Answer (score 0):

"Sociolinguistics" is the field of looking at how language is used in a social context - including the sorts of word choices you seem to be interested in.

Comment: Right, but I'm using sociolinguistics to compare the two dialects in a broader sense. I'm looking for the specific category that an informal contraction falls in so that I can put them in a table. Difference in rhoticity or pronunciation of vowels would go in the phonetics table, frequent use of the word "broad" to refer to a woman would go in the vocabulary table etc.

Comment: Of your categories, that would probably go in "vocabulary"

Comment: Yes, they're chunks of sedimentary language. Vocabulary is as good a term as anything. Unless you want to put sand and pebbles in different bins.